# How to deploy Play application using activator to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I am trying to deploy an activator app to Heroku. Without an Proc-file Heroku tells me that no cedar app is detected. When i add a Proc file and add

```
web: ./activator start -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
```

the startup fails.

How to get it running on Heroku?

**UPDATE**
The problem was a (not yet needed) package.json. Heroku obviously infered by that file that it is a node.js app. After renaming the app startet without a Proc file. But now i got unresolved dependencies for

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play_2.11;2.3.2: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.11;2.3.2: not found
[warn]  :: com.atlassian.jwt#jwt-core;1.2.3: not found
[warn]  :: com.atlassian.jwt#jwt-api;1.2.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

and solved that by adding

```
resolvers += "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Then I had the problem that we use SASS and it is not supported by Heroku. So I tried to deploy via the [sbt plugin](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionHeroku). That led to the following problem:

```
[error] (fashion-advice-common/compile:deployHeroku) You must stage your application before deploying it!
[error] (fashion-advice-customer/compile:deployHeroku) Could not find app ''. Check that herokuAppName setting is correct.
[error] (fashion-advice-stylist/compile:deployHeroku) Could not find app ''. Check that herokuAppName setting is correct.
```

Perhaps because we use 3 sub modules?

Comment: Can you share your project's build `build.sbt` and `project/*.[scala|sbt]` files? Do you have a simple(r) project on github that reproduces the issue to work with?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Procfile` should look more like this:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/name_of_app_repo -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
```

[Source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-scala#the-procfile)

Comment: that worked fine for me with Play 2.2. with 2.3 it didn't. solved the problem though. our web devs added a (not yet needed) package.json. heroku obviously infered by that file that it is a node.js app. after renaming the app startet without a Proc file.

Comment: I use it for Play 2.3 for all my apps. There is no difference between 2.2 and 2.3 in that respect. Heroku doesn't use activator, it just uses sbt.

Comment: There's no difference between `activator` and `sbt` once a project's been set up.

Comment: But I don't think heroku uses activator, so including that doesn't make sense. Even the [play 2.3.x docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionHeroku) say to do it this way.